# Strange design error when sending "select" from javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two sets of code, that basically sends a drop down list to a div from Javascript.

The strange thing is that I am basically sending the same thing in both the cases. But in the first code, the select drop down is perfectly being shown, while in the second code, it is being broken.

**Code 1:**

```
document.getElementById('start_day_div').innerHTML += "<select name='start_day' id='start_day'><option value='1'>option1</option><option value='2'>option2</option></select>";
```

[image: Output Screenshot of Code 1 (bordered area)]

**Code 2:** (Basically I am sending the same data as the code 1)

```
document.getElementById('start_day_div').innerHTML += "<select name='start_day' id='start_day'>";
document.getElementById('start_day_div').innerHTML += "<option value='1'>option1</option>";
document.getElementById('start_day_div').innerHTML += "<option value='2'>option2</option>";
document.getElementById('start_day_div').innerHTML += "</select>";
```

[image: Output Screenshot of Code 2 (bordered area)]

Any idea why this is happening for the same code?

Comment: `innerHTML` + `+=` = disaster waiting to happen. As you see here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After each call to `element.innerHTML +=` the browser will correct any incorrect html.

In your case you create the following html (which is invalid in itself as `<option>`'s cannot float around like that.)

```html
<select name='start_day' id='start_day'></select>
<option value='1'>option1</option>
<option value='2'>option2</option>
```

If you want to do it, you need to do it in one go. If you want to format it better, concatenate with a `+`:

```js
document.getElementById('start_day_div').innerHTML += "<select name='start_day' id='start_day'>"
                                                   +  "<option value='1'>option1</option>"
                                                   +  "<option value='2'>option2</option>"
                                                   +  "</select>";
```

```html
<div id="start_day_div"></div>
```

Comment: @Samurai8 Nicely explained. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are creating an incomplete select, most browsers will correct the error by closing the select html in order to render the control and make it an accessible object in the DOM with the normal select object properties etc. So afterwards the options are appended separately. If you inspect the resulting html this backs this theory up.